# Derivative of cost functions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus, machine-learning

We want to compute the derivative of the loss function $J(w)$ with respect to $w,$ where an expression for $J(w)$ is given below. [image]

I am almost clueless about how to solve this problem.Could someone help please?

Comment: Did you try small numbers like $n=1$ or $n=2$?  That might help understand what's going on.

Comment: This function is not differentiable.

Comment: Can you provide a little more info?

Comment: It looks piecewise differentiable, but the pieces are separated by hyperplanes on which the derivative is undefined (wherever $w^T x^{(i)} = y^{(i)}$ for some $i$). The global minimum, if there is one, will be at one of the  places where the derivative is not defined.

Comment: or do you want to take the sum of absolute squared, which can imply that the cost function is $\ell_2$-norm?

Comment: Actually, it is $\ell_1$-norm, which is not differentiable everywhere. But you can consider subdifferential.

Answer (score 2):

In this case when the function is of absolute value and therefore not differentiable, I was taught to do multiquadractic approximation of the form $|a| = \sqrt{a^2+k}$, where k is accuracy approximation (usually use $k = 0.0001$).

Therefore, $$J(w) = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{||Xw-y||^2+k}$$

$$\frac{\partial J(w)}{\partial w} = \frac{X^T(Xw-y)}{2\sqrt{k+||Xw-y||^2}}$$